# AnyMaps legend items don't use the correct icon colors

Tags: xml, apache-flex, icons

I use the AnyChart/AnyMap system to render custom maps for my site, currently version 6.0.11. We're displaying a map of the USA split up into regions, and each region is assigned a color according to a palette. All of that works great, however, we also have a legend at the bottom of the chart that's supposed to use the same colors as the Series data. For some reason the `<item>` elements seem to ignore any colors I assign manually, nor do they respect the `<icon color="%Color"...>` tag. The following is a snippet of the XML relevant to the legend in particular, based on the API specified at http://anychart.com/products/anychart/docs/xmlReference/index.html:

```
<anychart>
    <charts>
        <chart name="United States" plot_type="Map" template="state_template">
        <data_plot_settings>
            <map_series id_column="REGION_NAME" source="usa/country/states.amap">
            ...
            <chart_settings>
                <legend align="Center" align_by="DataPlot" enabled="True" ignore_auto_item="True" inside_dataplot="False" padding="5" position="Bottom">
                    <rows_padding><![CDATA[1]]></rows_padding>
                <format><![CDATA[{%Icon} {%Name} - 420{numDecimals:0,trailingZeros:0,decimalSeparator:,thousandsSeparator:}]]></format>
                <title enabled="False" />
                <icon color="%Color" series_type="Marker" type="SeriesIcon" />
                <items>
                    <item series="New England" source="Series">
                        <icon color="#E5E5E5" />
                    </item>
                    <item series="Middle Atlantic" source="Series">
                        <icon color="#E2D4D4" />
                    </item>
                    <item series="West South Central" source="Series">
                        <icon color="#DEE2D4" />
                    </item>
                    <item series="Mountain" source="Series">
                        <icon color="#DED4E2" />
                    </item>
                    <item series="Pacific" source="Series">
                        <icon color="#E2DBD4" />
                    </item>
                    <item series="East North Central" source="Series">
                        <icon color="#F4E0C3" />
                    </item>
                    <item series="West North Central" source="Series">
                        <icon color="#F2F1CE" />
                    </item>
                    <item series="South Atlantic" source="Series">
                        <icon color="#D4DCE2" />
                    </item>
                    <item series="East South Central" source="Series">
                        <icon color="#C6E5E1" />
                    </item>
                </items>
            </legend>
            </chart_settings>
        </chart>
    </charts>
</anychart>
```

It seems like it doesn't matter what color I put in the icons, or what format (it's supposed to accept strings like "red" and formats like RGB(255, 0 ,0), and #FF0000), it always renders the same set of colors. I can omit the section entirely and it still doesn't work. On a related note, if I change the `ignore_auto_item` parameter to False, or remove it entirely, the entire application blows up.

This is sort of a last resort as the AnyCharts fools aren't responding to tech support requests, and their sales guy redirected me to a friend of his who wants to charge me $150/hr. They're claiming it's something in my XML that's broken, but based on their API docs, my XML is perfectly fine. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

I should note that I'm using the AnyChartsFlex SWC that comes with their system, run through a custom Flex app. All this app does is provide a wrapper with additional functionality that users of my site require, and doesn't mess with the actual chart itself in any meaningful way (just adds a couple event listeners), nor does it touch the XML before it gets to their library to be rendered, and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed this is a bug in the AnyMaps software package. An interim solution is to add the exact color you want to each series item in the data, ie:

```
<series name="New England" palette="divisionColorPaletteNE" type="MapRegions" color="#E5E5E5">
```

When I do this, the legend finally uses the correct colors. So, while this fixed my immediate problem, setting the icon color for a specific legend item simply doesn't work, nor does setting the global color for all icons in the legend using the %Color keyword. The legend items don't respect colors coming from Palettes.

I hope anyone else dealing with this issue gets use from my misery figuring it out.